# bundle exec rails s failed because of unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundle

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and rbenv for the environment.
After successfully install the bundle, I try to start the server using `bundle exec rails s` however I got this following error

```
/home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/const.rb:21:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/version (LoadError)
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/const.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:122:in `require_relative'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:122:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:121:in `each'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:121:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/mario/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/mario/prayer-portal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the gem via "sudo bundle exec gem uninstall unicorn", then reinstalling it via standard "sudo bundle install". It will update the unicorn version.